# EFI No loader found. Configuration files in \loader\entries\*.conf are needed

Tags: boot, boot-loader, uefi

When I boot my install in EFI mode I see a EFI menu with no entries.  On hitting enter I get the error

```
No loader found. Configuration files in \loader\entries\*.conf are needed.
```

I have an entry in `/boot/loader/entries/`

```
# cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
title    Arch Linux
linuz    /vmlinuz-linux
initrd   /initramfs-linux.img
options  root=/dev/sda2 rw
```

And if I modify the timeout option in `/boot/loader/loader.conf` that is reflected in the EFI boot menu.  So the boot-loader is finding `loader.conf` correctly but isn't finding anything in `entries` or that folder at all.

When chrooted, `bootctl status` outputs the correct partuuid of my ESP.  I am at a lost for what could be wrong.  Why isn't the boot-loader finding my menu entries?

Comment: No that is exactly what was on my screen. I thought that's just how uefi was.

Comment: are you using elilo or something other than grub?

Comment: This is my favourite bookmark on the topic: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: @psusi systemd-boot

Comment: Oh jesus... systemd is trying to take over yet another major part of the system?

Comment: @psusi. It used to be gummiboot.  Its weird for a systemd process is starting before systemd but let's avoid a flame war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just a typo.  gummiboot can find arch.conf just fine it's just not a valid entry.

In arch.conf change the option `linuz` to `linux`:

```
title    Arch Linux
linux    /vmlinuz-linux
initrd   /initramfs-linux.img
options  root=/dev/sda2 rw
```